# loops in gnuplot inside the plot command

Tags: variables, for-loop, gnuplot

I am having trouble using a for loop in gnuplot inside the plot command.  Here is a pared down gnuplot script, which focuses on the parts that aren't working:

```
set multiplot layout 1, 3 title "Convergence Plots"
planeIter=4

do for [ringIter=0:20:10] {
    if (ringIter == 0) {ringName="outer"} else {if (ringIter == 10) {ringName="middle"} else {ringName="inner"}}
    set title "Pressure in ".ringName." ring"
    plot for [quadIter=0:90:30] path1 every ::5 using 1:(1 + planeIter + ringIter + quadIter) notitle   # title quadName.' quadrant' with lines
#   if (quadIter == 0) {quadName="first"} else {if (quadIter == 30) {quadName="second"} else {if (quadIter == 60) {quadName="third"} else {quadName="fourth"}}}
}
```

My questions are:

1. Where/how can I include the (commented out) if/else statement, so that I can replace 'notitle' in the line above with the 'title' after the # symbol?
2. The lines plotted should be of the following columns in p: (1:5, 1:35, 1:65, 1:95), (1:15, 1:45, 1:75, 1:105) and (1:25, 1:55, 1:85, 1:115) but instead of taking the value in the second column (5, 35, 65, ...) it plots the column number (i.e. a constant).  How can I get the plot command to select the values inside the columns?

I have included an image of what it looks like and what it should look like (below), which I have generated by not using for loops and variables for quadName.

[image: gnuplot_image]

The file, p, is a list of numbers, each row containing 121 columns.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a variable to specify the selected column, you must use `column(var)`, i.e. in your case it would be `using 1:(column(1 + planeIter + ringIter + quadIter))`.

To select a word for the title, you can define a function which returns the respective string, like:

```
quadName(x) = (x == 0 ? "first" : (x == 30 ? "second" : (x == 60 ? "third" : "fourth")))
plot for [quadIter=0:90:30] path1 using 1:(column(1 + planeIter + ringIter + quadIter)) \
    title quadName(quadIter).' quadrant' with lines
```

Alternatively you could also use the `word` function, which might be nicer for more selections:

```
quadName = "first second third fourth"
plot for [quadIter=0:90:30] path1 using 1:(column(1 + planeIter + ringIter + quadIter)) \
    title word(quadName, (quadIter / 30) + 1)
```